# url no encontrada en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, poo, composer

Hola amigos de StackOverFlow tengo una duda con las rutas en laravel estoy creando rutas pero al momento se usar rutas sin el .php no puedo utilizarlas ya que me aparece el mensaje 404
Acon tinuacion muestro el codigo:

```
  <?php

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

  Route::get('/', function () {
  //devuelve la vista-pagina "welcome"
  //return view('welcomes');

  //return "wecome to principal site"; //view('welcome to principal site');
  });


  Route::get('cursos', function()  {
   return "cursos";
  });



  //Paso de ruta por variables

  Route::get('cursos/{curso}', function($curso) {

  return "bienvenido al curso {$curso}";

  });
```

Lei tambien que modificando el archivo .htaccess puedes abrir archivos .php sin la extencion por lo cual edite el archivo .htaccess que esta en el directorio public/ que me creo por defecto composer.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
 </IfModule>
```

Reinicie mi servidor apache con:

```
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Pero no me detecta las rutas cabe hacer la mension que en el videotutorial que sigo no crea ni los archivos ni los directorios y en el video si carga correctamente las rutas :v .

Answer (score 0):

Solucion: Hola amigos parece ser que me habia liado con esto de los servers jaja ya pude resolver mi problema
este error se soluciona primeramente entrando al directorio del proyecto

```
  cd dir/html_public/your-proyect-dir
```

y luego correr el servidor dentro del directorio de trabajo

```
 php artisan serve
```

Si se ejecuto dentro del directorio se iniciara correctamente el servidor

```
 Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
 [Tue Jan  4 16:20:11 2022] PHP 7.4.25 Development Server    
 (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
```

Si se ejecuta estas instrucciones fuera del directorio de trabajo dara un error de salida

```
 Could not open input file: artisan
```

Espero que mi solucion le sirva a los nuevos como yo XD .

Comment: ostias me estoy enamorando de este framework me siento exitado :v.